# How to intersect two geodatabases in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, intersection, file-geodatabase

Trying to intersect features from two file geodatabases in model builder. However, the databases can not be connected to the intersect as input features.

Second opting - put all features into one database, but in this case it will just run on individual features without results.

Each database has several points or polygon layers, which are not necessary overlap.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The intersect tool expects a *feature class* or a *layer* as input. But you try to use a *geodatabase* as input.

Add two feature classes (or layer) to ModellBuilder instead of two geodatabases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the relevant feature class as the input and not the Geodatabase.